# Index was outside the bounds of the array!

Tags: c#

При инициализации 21 строки кода выдаёт данную ошибку!Как её можно исправить?

```
namespace Pacman
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char[,] map = ReadMap("map.txt");
            DrawMap(map);
        }
        private static char[,] ReadMap(string panth)
        {
            string[] file = File.ReadAllLines("map.txt");
            char[,] map = new char[GetMaxLengthOfLine(file),file.Length];
            for (int x = 0; x < map.GetLength(0); x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < map.GetLength(1); y++)
                {
                    map[x, y] = file[y][x];
                }
            }
            return map;
        }
        private static int GetMaxLengthOfLine(string[] lines)
        {
            int maxLength = lines[0].Length;
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                if (line.Length > maxLength)
                {
                    maxLength = line.Length;
                }
            }
            return maxLength;
        }
        private static void DrawMap(char[,] map)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < map.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < map.GetLength(0); x++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(map[x,y]);
                }
                Console.Write("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
}[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Неверная логика работы:

ищется максимальная длина строки `GetMaxLengthOfLine(file)` - поэтому при попытке взять символ у более коротких строк и происходит ошибка.

Способ решения зависит от ожидаемого результата. Можно проверить длину строки и если в ней не хватает символов установить какой-то дефолтный

```
map[x, y] = file[y].Length > x ? file[y][x] : '';
```